# AngularJS template parse error when using pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I am trying to sanitize text thats coming from db i dont control and show it as html. My broken code looks as follows.

```
 <li *ngFor="let comm of commList|async;">
    <div class="notifBody">
      <span>
        <div [innerHTML]={{comm.text|safe : 'html'}}> </div>
      </span>
    </div>
 </li>
```

The error i am getting is as follows

```
compiler.es5.js:1694 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "div". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("
      <hr>
      <span>
        <div [innerHTML]={{comm.text|safe : 'html'}}>[ERROR ->]</div>
      </span>
    </div>
```

I am guessing i am missing something in my syntax but not sure what.

If i remove the safe pipe as follows it works fine and renders the text as html....(not sanitized).

```
    <div class="notifBody">
      <span>
        <div [innerHTML]=comm.text></div>
      </span>
    </div>
```

The following pipe test also works as expected but the text wont be rendered as html.

```
<div class="notifBody">
  <span>
    {{comm.text|safe : 'html'}}
  </span>
</div>
```

The Safe pipe just sanitizes the passed string using Sanitizer from angular core as follows.

```
 import { Pipe, Sanitizer, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';
 ...
 public transform(value: string, type: string): string {
    switch (type) {
        case 'html':
            return this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, value);
    ...}}
```

Thanks!

Comment: missing a " here: `*ngFor="let comm of commList|async;>` ?

Comment: Also missing double quotes around your HTML attribute values.

Comment: @OvidiuDolha updated.(accidentally removed the last quote when posting here). JB : not sure what you are referring.

Comment: try,  `<div innerHTML={{comm.text|safe : 'html'}}></div>`, without square brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can use :

```
[innerHTML]="comm.text|safe : 'html'"
```

or

```
innerHTML="{{comm.text|safe : 'html'}}"
```

But you have mixed both syntax `[innerHTML]={{comm.text|safe : 'html'}}`

You can read more about it here : https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation----

Comment: The first one works but not the second suggestion.Thanks! Any explanation what {{ }} does differently?

Comment: @Davvit. was missing double quotes , please try second method also.